# How to quickly convert an immediate in a register to chars for storage in string

Tags: assembly, ascii, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

I have a counter in my program.
I want to store the finished counter in a buffer so i can send it to mmio display.My problem is that i need a char representation of a number so that i can store it in string buffer.

Comment: repeatedly divide by base to get each digit, convert to ascii characters

Comment: ah see, so in my register I have 0x000000b. How do i convert these to asci? (I figured with lower values i could just add it to ascii for 0)

Comment: Immediates exist in the instruction stream.  By the time they get into registers, it doesn't matter how they got there.  But if your integer comes from an assemble-time constant, you can have an assemble-time constant ASCII bytes as well, like `li $t0, '1234'`  (note the single quotes, making it a 32-bit / 4-byte multi-character ASCII constant.)  Then you can simply store `$t0` into your string buffer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the instructivel responses.  I ended up using rem to get digits from smallest to largest then added the digit to  '0' and stored in a buffer. Finally I just reversed the contents of buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make things simpler, you could first implement your logic in a C or C++ program and translate it to assembly code by hand or with the help of a compiler.

[For example, translate to hex representation](https://godbolt.org/z/4FjPnY):

```
void u2hexs(unsigned n, char* buf)
{
  buf += 8;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    unsigned digit = n & 15;
    unsigned ch = (digit < 10) ? '0' + digit : 'A' + digit - 10;
    *--buf = ch;
    n >>= 4;
  }
}
```

Translates into:

```
u2hexs:
        b       $L4
        addiu   $3,$5,8

$L8:
        addiu   $2,$2,48
        addiu   $3,$3,-1
        sb      $2,0($3)
        beq     $5,$3,$L9
        srl     $4,$4,4

$L4:
        andi    $2,$4,0xf
        sltu    $6,$2,10
        bne     $6,$0,$L8
        nop

        addiu   $2,$2,55
        addiu   $3,$3,-1
        sb      $2,0($3)
        bne     $5,$3,$L4
        srl     $4,$4,4

$L9:
        j       $31
        nop
```

There's more than one way of doing it. You could remove the extra branch and instead compute the constant that's added to `digit` from the value that the `sltiu` instruction returns. You could perhaps use conditional move instructions (`movn` and `movz`).

You could also define a character array containing the 16 hex digits (from '0' to 'F') and use `digit` as an index to extract the right character and thus avoid all the trouble of calculating the addend.